# Custom view with CGRectMake location x and y providing incorrect view

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode7, cgrectmake

Previous i am using Xcode 6.4 or below, In that I didn't notify this type issues. but now  I am getting noticeable problems in Xcode 7.2 in related CGRectMake x,y Position.

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UIView *smallView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, 100, 100)];
    smallView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:smallView];
    NSLog(@"%f",smallView.frame.origin.x);// 137.500000
```

above snip code, the position of x & y not perfect. the below image is output .
[image]

but if i add center=self.view.ceter It will come to center. the output is [image]

```
 smallView.center=self.view.center;
```

the problem is , in both case x & y position values same ,

```
  NSLog(@"%f\n%f\n%f\f%f ",screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2,self.view.center.x,self.view.center.y);
```

Why they will show different result, how can i do without using center property. or Shall go for Autolayout .

Comment: `self.view.center.x` would not change because `self.view` is the top most view in the controller.

Comment: @gabbler then why it shows wrong view position . x and y in CGRectnake

Comment: Which line of code are you talking about, what do you expect?

Comment: @gabbler CGRectmake x and y values same as self.view.center.x and y.

Comment: @gabbler but it shows different result

Comment: UIView *smallView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, 100, 100)]; i want from this code. middle my uiview

Comment: You are setting smallView's top left corner to self.view's center, it should be like this, `CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - 50, screenHeight/2 - 50, 100, 100)`